# Compiling C in Visual Studio 2010 Not Creating .EXE File

Tags: c, compilation

I'm able to debug a C program in Visual Studio 2008 and build it. However, the build process doesn't seem to leave an .exe in the folder it builds in. Regardless of if I choose Release or Debug. Could the .exe be sent somewhere else? How can I tell?

Contents of the Debug folder under the main folder of the project:

`cl.command.1.tlog

CL.read.1.tlog

CL.write.1.tlog

ConsoleApp.Build.CppClean.log

ConsoleApp.exe.embed.manifest

ConsoleApp.exe.embed.manifest.res

ConsoleApp.exe.intermediate.manifest

ConsoleApp.lastbuildstate

ConsoleApp.log

ConsoleApp.obj

ConsoleApp_manifest.rc

link-cvtres.read.1.tlog

link-cvtres.write.1.tlog

link.1504-cvtres.read.1.tlog

link.1504-cvtres.write.1.tlog

link.1504.read.1.tlog

link.1504.write.1.tlog

link.command.1.tlog

link.read.1.tlog

link.write.1.tlog

mt.command.1.tlog

mt.read.1.tlog

mt.write.1.tlog

rc.command.1.tlog

rc.read.1.tlog

rc.write.1.tlog

stdafx.obj

vc100.idb

vc100.pdb`

Comment: What is the target? Are you sure you're building an executable, not a library?

Comment: If you can debug it, it must have an executable in the output folder.

Comment: Have you seen the debug folder just below your project directory, i.e. one directory above your source files???

Comment: Not seeing the file there. I'll update question with dir file listing.

Comment: try searching for `*.exe` in the project folder (F3). or pause the program in debug mode, search for the exe in task manager's process list and right click->properties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click the project node and open the property page:-

In General node in Configuration Properties.
There you'll see two fields:-

1. Output Directory
2. Target Extension.
   if the target extension is .exe then the things are fine.
   Look in the Output DIrectory, you'll find the executable.

EDIT:- You are looking at wrong place.
You have to see here (an example):-

```
C:\Documents and Settings\USER\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\C\The_c\Debug
```

And you are seeing here

```
C:\Documents and Settings\USER\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\C\The_c\The_c\Debug
```

That is two directory above the present directory.

Comment: Hmm. Those settings seem correct and I still can't find the .exe.

Comment: @brun:- I have edited ,please look two directory above for debug folder(After rebuilding).Expecting your Output directory is marked something like `.\Debug`

Comment: I'm working in C:\SOURCE\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp and I have no .exes in C:\SOURCE\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\Debug or Release

Comment: look at C:\SOURCE\ConsoleApp\Debug\  (For a debug build)

Comment: Thanks. I kept looking in the subfolder ConsoleApp. Thought I was losing my mind. +1 and answer

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking the Output Path in the project properties?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error when (for some reason) multiple MSBuild.exe's were to be found in the taskmanager. I killed them all, and it worked again.

Answer (score 1):

I found that it was because of the counter intuitive way that visual studio builds the directory structure when you make a new console app. You get two  folders and two debug folders viz

```
├───MakeSubscriber
│   ├───Debug
│   ├───ipch
│   │   └───makesubscriber-67e243a
│   └───MakeSubscriber
│       └───Debug
```

so all the tlog  and intermediate files go in one Debug folder and the exe, ilk and pdb go in the other

Answer (score 1):

I have spent about 3 hours trying figure this out, finally got it:
You'll notice that in the project file, there is a debug folder. In this folder should NORMALLY be an

```
an .exe file, 
a .ilk file, 
and a .pdb file.
```

These were missing for me. How I fixed it:

I copied those 3 files from another project's debug folder and pasted them into my project's Debug folder. Then I renamed them to match my C++ file(.cpp)'s name. This isn't enough however, you have to save it like that and then close Visual Studio, then open the project file again from Windows explorer.

That did it for me!! Fiiinalllly!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue for my whole class. The problem was when doing a win32 console application empty and then creating .cpp, the program was not adding the .cpp to the end of the .cpp file name. When I added it manually, such as practice.cpp instead of just practice, it created the .exe file. It worked for everyone having the issue.