# How to start .exe file contained in my project in c#? 

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Embedding an external executable inside a C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798655/embedding-an-external-executable-inside-a-c-sharp-program)

I create project "MyProj" and add to resource program "This.exe"...

How could I start "this.exe" in "MyProj.exe"?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: If you mean start the right executable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951694/compiling-c-in-visual-studio-2010-not-creating-exe-file/11951832#11951832

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you added the .exe to your project, got to the properties window then change the `Build action` to `Content` and `Copy to output directory` to `Always Copy` or `Copy if newer`

[image]

To run the Application use :

```
Process.Start("This.exe");
```

Comment: @Azure You're welcome :). [Here's an article](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) on how to better ask questions to avoid getting down voted and remember to always accept the answers that solve your problems.

Comment: okey, I will read article about ask questions :). And there is any way to contain "this.exe" into project? becouse your way is copy "this.exe" to destination where is "starting" program (MyProj.exe create this.exe and start it and I need hide this.exe before user), I hope that you understand me :).

Comment: @Azure If I understand you correctly, you could embed the .Exe file as a resource.

Comment: yes :), and I [find how start app from resource...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798655/embedding-an-external-executable-inside-a-c-sharp-program)  thx for your time ;)

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>F5</kbd> or go to `Debug -> Start Debugging` (this is the same as hitting the `Play` button).

If you don't want debugging then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> or go to `Debug -> Start without debugging`.

**EDIT:**
After the author's edit I think this is the answer: [Launching an application (.EXE) from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240171/launching-a-application-exe-from-c)

Or maybe: [Run exe file added as resource in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030880/run-exe-file-added-as-resource-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I'm not such a beginner... I closer this probelm, I create project "MyProj" and add to resource program "This.exe"... how I start "this.exe" in "MyProj.exe"?

Comment: Well you definitely stated your problem wrong, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240171/launching-a-application-exe-from-c

Comment: yep I apologize, I do not speak English very well...