# silently execute a MSI package from C#

Tags: c#, windows-installer

Newbie question, let me try and make this as clear as possible. I have a program that needs to silently execute a msi package (well multiple but that's not the problem)

The MSI packages are contained in a folder located in the same directory as my program. I've given it a simple name of "InstallFiles" for the time being.

I'm not keen on using the full path name eg. C:\my program\another directory\another directory etc because it'll be put on multiple PC's, old and new, in which case the drive letter can change. So far I have:

```
install.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec";
install.StartInfo.Arguments = "/i F:\\InstallFiles\\JRE.msi";
install.Start();
install.WaitForExit();
```

However, when its launched it only gives me the Windows Installer switch information and then terminates, how do I get it to run and how would I go about changing the file path?

Comment: Take a look: [Application.StartupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executing of .msi file should be like .exe file that here is your answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12436300/359170

start the application with this code :

```
Process.Start("yourfile.msi");
```

and it don't need the full path, it adds current directory to the file name you written there.

But

```
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

gets the current executed file directory. And you can get the file path by adding just the name of the file to it like this :

```
 string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\yourfile.msi";
```

Comment: trying this solution now, keep getting "The specified executable is not a valid win32 application"

Comment: EDIT - if I create a simple batch file with "msiexec /i "filename" /quiet it works"

Answer (score 2):

use with the following switch:

/q[n|b|r|f]

```
    Sets user interface level
    n - No UI
    b - Basic UI
    r - Reduced UI
```

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for detailed commandline options.