# executing an vb script from another project bud in the same solution in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, wix

i am trying to call a VB script that i made that in the same solution bud in another project, it is a C# project with windows forms and WIX.

i am building an .MSI installer and when i arrive at a certain form i want it to execute a VB script automatically. the thing is i have no idea how to call a VB script from a C# form. since this is the first time i work with C# and i am not very skilled when it comes to programming.

can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was already answered on Stackoverflow several times. For example in this thread: [How to call a VBScript file in a C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200422/how-to-call-a-vbscript-file-in-a-c-sharp-application)

Give it a try, if it won't work out, ask again with specific examples of your source code, because that would be a special scenario then.

Comment: thank you, it does work now. it is strange i didn't find that page since i have searched for more than an hour for an answer on the forum. do you have an idea where i can find some basic information regarding common functions such as opening files/ executing and more that might come in handy for building an installer? a good basic tutorial regarding c# is fine too because my biggest problem now is that i dont know where to start searching or what to look for.

Comment: The link I've pasted above is also applicable for almost any other file execution, you might want to trigger in C#. Afaik the Process-Class is very handy when it comes down to that. A few links you should take a look at [1](http://www.dotnetperls.com/process)  [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448180/silently-execute-a-msi-package-from-c-sharp)